Will Air Asia check my luggage to the final destination on an international flight with a connection?
I am an Indian passport holder.
I have recently booked a connecting flight from Bali To Ahmedabad via Kuala Lumpur. Both are Air Asia flights. Thought flights were connecting I got  different PNRs for my booking.
My question is, will Air Asia Check through our luggage to the final destination ?

Did you book direct with the airline or via an agent? What did Air Asia say when you asked them?

Can you tell us: (a) whether you booked on the Air Asia website, Air Asia app, or some other place, (b) what are the flights involved and (c) the date of travel? Air Asia were originally a point-to-point carrier only, but a few years ago they introduced "Fly-Thru" for some flight combinations through some airports like KUL, but not necessarily all of them, and it's hard to make sense of it. Having the specific data would allow us to try to reproduce the booking and try to figure out whether you can be checked-through or not.

If you booked AirAsia's "FLY-THRU" service, your baggage will be transferred for you and you do not need it pick it up.
If you did not explicitly book and pay extra for this, you will need to pickup and re-check the bags.

I'm not sure this is really the way it works these days. I think the FAQ on the topic is quite outdated, as the booking engine on their site does not mention Fly-thru anywhere, but still states that some connections are protected.

@jcaron I just tried a dummy DPS-KUL-AMD bookings and while the word "Fly-Thru" was indeed missing, some connections were labeled "Self-Transfer" while others were not. Not quite sure what to make of this...
